# How to new up a controller that "needs" application?

Tags: ember.js, ember-testing

Before adding my "needs" the controller looked like this

```
var MyController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    wat: function() {
        return true;
    }.property()
});
```

This allowed me to write really simple unit tests like so

```
test('wat always returns true ... huh', function() {
    var controller = new MyController();
    var wat = controller.get('wat');
    ok(wat);
});
```

But after I added a "needs" block like so ...

```
var MyController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: 'application',
    wat: function() {
        return true;
    }.property()
});
```

The "new up" won't work and QUnit / ember is throwing an error like so

"Please be sure this controller was instantiated with a container"

Without saying "pull in / use ember-qunit" what other options do I have here? Can I simply slam in a "stub" to satisfy the container requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ember-qunit (which I'm not the biggest fan of) you can grab the controller using `this.subject()` and setting up the module like so:

```
moduleFor('controller:comments', 'Comments Controller', {
  needs: ['controller:post']
});
```

http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/testing-controllers/#toc_testing-controller-needs

If you weren't using Ember Qunit you could just use the container to fetch the controller ([Initialized dependency not present when testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373165/initialized-dependency-not-present-when-testing/24373988#24373988)).  Here's a helper:

```
Ember.Test.registerHelper('containerLookup',
  function(app, look) {
    return app.__container__.lookup(look);
  }
);
```

And you could use it easily like so:

```
test("root lists 3 colors", function(){
  var c = containerLookup('controller:foo');

  ok(c.get('controllers.bar.tr'));
  ok(!c.get('controllers.bar.fa'));
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tumeko/edit

Comment: very cool - quick question that I'm unclear on w/ the 2nd approach you show here. Will this return the same instance each time (assuming I have that specific controller type configured as a singleton)? I'm looking for a "quick" and "easy" way to create truly new instances each time (is this possible when I use needs and want to skip out on ember-qunit?)

Comment: It would return the same instance over and over, except we use `App.reset()` between each test which creates a new container giving us new controllers each time, example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tumeko/3/edit